# subtract one day from a pandas dataframe date column

Tags: pandas, datetime, type-promotion

Sorry for my lack of Pandas and datetime ability. I have tried but something seems to be just outside my current limited skillset.

I am using a date column (FinalStartPunch) which is typed to datetime64[ns] and if the Hour is at 0, then subtract one day from a datetime64[ns] column (date). If the FinalStartPunch hour is not a 0, then just copy the date column value as is.

sample data:

```
date         FinalStartPunch
6/27/2015   27JUN2015:14:15:00
7/23/2015   23JUL2015:13:31:00
7/23/2015   23JUL2015:18:43:00
8/15/2015   15AUG2015:18:35:00
8/15/2015   15AUG2015:23:30:00
8/16/2015   16AUG2015:00:00:00
1/30/2016   30JAN2016:18:25:00
1/30/2016   30JAN2016:23:52:00
1/31/2016   31JAN2016:00:00:00
8/13/2016   13AUG2016:18:30:00
8/13/2016   13AUG2016:23:58:00
8/14/2016   14AUG2016:00:00:00
1/28/2017   28JAN2017:18:30:00
1/28/2017   28JAN2017:23:57:00
1/29/2017   29JAN2017:00:00:00
```

Key code section:

```
df['New'] = df['date'] - pd.Timedelta(1, unit='D')  ### This one works
print(df.dtypes)

conds = [df['FinalStartPunch'].dt.hour == 0, df['FinalStartPunch'].dt.hour > 0]

choices = [df['date'] - pd.Timedelta(1, unit='D'), df['date']]

df['Date1'] = np.select(conds, choices, default=0)
```

The Error:  invalid type promotion

The df['New'] works with the same code in the choices row which seems to be the problem causing the error.

Perhaps a Numpy issue and I need a different approach to doing this?

Any help - so greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `.dt.hour == 0` with `np.where()` to identify rows where the hour is 0 and `- pd.tseries.offsets.Day()` to subtract a day.

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
df['FinalStartPunch'] = pd.to_datetime(df['FinalStartPunch'], format='%d%b%Y:%H:%M:%S')
df['Date1'] = df['FinalStartPunch'].where((df['FinalStartPunch'].dt.hour != 0),
                                                    df['date'] - pd.tseries.offsets.Day())
df
Out[37]: 
         date     FinalStartPunch               Date1
0  2015-06-27 2015-06-27 14:15:00 2015-06-27 14:15:00
1  2015-07-23 2015-07-23 13:31:00 2015-07-23 13:31:00
2  2015-07-23 2015-07-23 18:43:00 2015-07-23 18:43:00
3  2015-08-15 2015-08-15 18:35:00 2015-08-15 18:35:00
4  2015-08-15 2015-08-15 23:30:00 2015-08-15 23:30:00
5  2015-08-16 2015-08-16 00:00:00 2015-08-15 00:00:00
6  2016-01-30 2016-01-30 18:25:00 2016-01-30 18:25:00
7  2016-01-30 2016-01-30 23:52:00 2016-01-30 23:52:00
8  2016-01-31 2016-01-31 00:00:00 2016-01-30 00:00:00
9  2016-08-13 2016-08-13 18:30:00 2016-08-13 18:30:00
10 2016-08-13 2016-08-13 23:58:00 2016-08-13 23:58:00
11 2016-08-14 2016-08-14 00:00:00 2016-08-13 00:00:00
12 2017-01-28 2017-01-28 18:30:00 2017-01-28 18:30:00
13 2017-01-28 2017-01-28 23:57:00 2017-01-28 23:57:00
14 2017-01-29 2017-01-29 00:00:00 2017-01-28 00:00:00
```

Comment: Thanks. This worked great with just a slight change due to my poor communication.  The thing I would also love to know is why the other method did not work.  Still have to figure out this date typing conundrum.  So nice to receive help from talented people with answers.

Comment: @user2016566 , no problem! Please accept if it helped you solve. In regards to np.slect, that usually works for me, but I only use it with multiple conditions and results. Not sure why it didn’t work with just one condition and one result.

Answer (score 3):

```
df.loc[df['FinalStartPunch'].dt.hour == 0, 'FinalStartPunch'] = df['FinalStartPunch'] - pd.Timedelta(1, unit='D')
```

You can just use .loc to search for those times, then subtract the day.