# Pandas pivot + date slicing: group by periods of time with partial overlap

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, python-datetime, pandas-explode

I am trying to find a way to 'pivot' my pandas dataframe, but keeping my index by sliced dates. The end goal is to create a range for each index in which each attributes and their values are matched.

I reached the expected output using for loops and other non-vectorized ways, but I would be looking for a vectorized solution since my input dataframe might be quite big.

I am using python 3.11 and pandas>=2.0.0.

Here is an input example :

```
    index   attribute   start_date  end_date    value
0   index_1 attribute_1 2022-01-01  2022-02-01  1
1   index_1 attribute_1 2022-02-01  2023-01-01  2
2   index_1 attribute_2 2022-01-01  2023-01-01  3
3   index_2 attribute_3 2022-01-01  2023-01-01  4
4   index_3 attribute_4 2022-01-01  2023-01-01  5
```

What I am trying to obtain is this :

```
    index   start_date  end_date    attribute_1 attribute_2 attribute_3 attribute_4
0   index_1 2022-01-01  2022-02-01  1           3           None        None
1   index_1 2022-02-01  2023-01-01  2           3           None        None
2   index_2 2022-01-01  2023-01-01  None        None        4           None
3   index_3 2022-01-01  2023-01-01  None        None        None        5
```

Here is a dictionnary to reproduce the input dataframe :

```
from datetime import datetime
{
    "index": ["index_1", "index_1", "index_1", "index_2", "index_3"],
    "attribute": ["attribute_1", "attribute_1", "attribute_2", "attribute_3", "attribute_4"],
    "start_date": [datetime(2022, 1, 1), datetime(2022, 2, 1), datetime(2022, 1, 1), datetime(2022, 1, 1), datetime(2022, 1, 1)],
    "end_date": [datetime(2022, 2, 1), datetime(2023, 1, 1), datetime(2023, 1, 1), datetime(2023, 1, 1), datetime(2023, 1, 1)],
    "value": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To begin with, two modifications I had to bring to your input data for proper processing:

##### Actual input used

###### 1) Poor practice: "index" assigned as var name

Refrain from using `index` for naming variables, or columns names in your case. Potential conflicts calling `df.index` later. To avoid confusions, I have named your 'index' with high caps: 'INDEX'.

###### 2) Dates overlap: end of period == beginning of next period

For example: According to your input, *index_1*'s *attribute_1* on day 2022-02-01 takes 2 values: both 1 AND 2 at the same time. That is bound to cause unecessary problems. Hence I have made `end_date` an end of month, instead of the first day of the next, as in [subtract one day from a pandas dataframe date column](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63855270/12846804):

```py
# Removing one day from end_dates
df['end_date'] = df['end_date'] - pd.tseries.offsets.Day()
```

Alternatively you could:

- use months as unit of time, provided this assumption holds for your full input data.
- or specify an hour.

###### Following these remarks, dataframe used as input:

```py
     INDEX    attribute start_date   end_date  value
0  INDEX_1  attribute_1 2022-01-01 2022-01-31      1
1  INDEX_1  attribute_1 2022-02-01 2022-12-31      2
2  INDEX_1  attribute_2 2022-01-01 2022-12-31      3
3  INDEX_2  attribute_3 2022-01-01 2022-12-31      4
4  INDEX_3  attribute_4 2022-01-01 2022-12-31      5
```

Please confirm that those changes are ok with you.
Now moving on to the actual solution:

---

##### Strategy

1. Pivot *attributes* from index to columns
2. Reshape dataframe into time series, as in [Convert dataframe with start and end date to daily data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57334097/convert-dataframe-with-start-and-end-date-to-daily-data) in 2 steps:

   2a. Merge the tuples (start_date, end_date) into time spans,

   2b. Then *explode* the time spans into full daily time series,
3. Aggregate the time series into the requested form

   3a. Merge data corresponding to each day: **group by INDEX + days**

   3b. Then recreate the relevant start and end dates: **group by INDEX + attributes**, aggregating timespans by *min-max* days, as in [Max and Min date in pandas groupby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25024797/max-and-min-date-in-pandas-groupby)

---

##### Processing

###### 1. Pivot *attributes* from index to columns

```py
df_pivot = df.pivot_table(values  ='value',
                          columns = 'attribute',
                          index   = ['INDEX','start_date','end_date']).reset_index()

attribute    INDEX start_date   end_date  attribute_1  attribute_2  attribute_3  attribute_4
0          INDEX_1 2022-01-01 2022-01-31          1.0          NaN          NaN          NaN
1          INDEX_1 2022-01-01 2022-12-31          NaN          3.0          NaN          NaN
2          INDEX_1 2022-02-01 2022-12-31          2.0          NaN          NaN          NaN
3          INDEX_2 2022-01-01 2022-12-31          NaN          NaN          4.0          NaN
4          INDEX_3 2022-01-01 2022-12-31          NaN          NaN          NaN          5.0
```

###### 2. Reshape dataframe into time series

```py
df_pivot['timespan'] = df_pivot.apply(lambda row: pd.date_range(row['start_date'], row['end_date']), axis=1)

attribute    INDEX start_date   end_date  attribute_1  attribute_2  attribute_3  attribute_4                                           timespan
0          INDEX_1 2022-01-01 2022-01-31          1.0          NaN          NaN          NaN  DatetimeIndex(['2022-01-01', '2022-01-02', '20...
1          INDEX_1 2022-01-01 2022-12-31          NaN          3.0          NaN          NaN  DatetimeIndex(['2022-01-01', '2022-01-02', '20...
2          INDEX_1 2022-02-01 2022-12-31          2.0          NaN          NaN          NaN  DatetimeIndex(['2022-02-01', '2022-02-02', '20...
3          INDEX_2 2022-01-01 2022-12-31          NaN          NaN          4.0          NaN  DatetimeIndex(['2022-01-01', '2022-01-02', '20...
4          INDEX_3 2022-01-01 2022-12-31          NaN          NaN          NaN          5.0  DatetimeIndex(['2022-01-01', '2022-01-02', '20...
```

```py
TS = df_pivot.explode('timespan', ignore_index=True)
             .drop(columns=['start_date', 'end_date'])

attribute    INDEX  attribute_1  attribute_2  attribute_3  attribute_4   timespan
0          INDEX_1          1.0          NaN          NaN          NaN 2022-01-01
1          INDEX_1          1.0          NaN          NaN          NaN 2022-01-02
2          INDEX_1          1.0          NaN          NaN          NaN 2022-01-03
3          INDEX_1          1.0          NaN          NaN          NaN 2022-01-04
4          INDEX_1          1.0          NaN          NaN          NaN 2022-01-05
...            ...          ...          ...          ...          ...        ...
1455       INDEX_3          NaN          NaN          NaN          5.0 2022-12-27
1456       INDEX_3          NaN          NaN          NaN          5.0 2022-12-28
1457       INDEX_3          NaN          NaN          NaN          5.0 2022-12-29
1458       INDEX_3          NaN          NaN          NaN          5.0 2022-12-30
1459       INDEX_3          NaN          NaN          NaN          5.0 2022-12-31
```

At this point, one day still appears several times within each INDEX. You will see if you plot `TS.plot(y='timespan')`

###### 3. Aggregate the time series into the requested form

```py
TS = TS.groupby(by=['INDEX','timespan'])
       .max()
       .reset_index()

attribute    INDEX   timespan  attribute_1  attribute_2  attribute_3  attribute_4
0          INDEX_1 2022-01-01          1.0          3.0          NaN          NaN
1          INDEX_1 2022-01-02          1.0          3.0          NaN          NaN
2          INDEX_1 2022-01-03          1.0          3.0          NaN          NaN
3          INDEX_1 2022-01-04          1.0          3.0          NaN          NaN
4          INDEX_1 2022-01-05          1.0          3.0          NaN          NaN
...            ...        ...          ...          ...          ...          ...
1090       INDEX_3 2022-12-27          NaN          NaN          NaN          5.0
1091       INDEX_3 2022-12-28          NaN          NaN          NaN          5.0
1092       INDEX_3 2022-12-29          NaN          NaN          NaN          5.0
1093       INDEX_3 2022-12-30          NaN          NaN          NaN          5.0
1094       INDEX_3 2022-12-31          NaN          NaN          NaN          5.0
```

Now each day appears only once per INDEX.

*Choice of agg function:* We took care that there was only ever one possible value per day per attribute per INDEX, so any agg function could do. However, aggregating by either `max()` (or `min()`) will preserve the NaNs. Unlike `sum()`, which converts them to zeroes.

```py
df_final = TS.groupby(by=['INDEX','attribute_1','attribute_2','attribute_3','attribute_4'], dropna=False)
             .agg({'timespan' : [min, max]})
             .reset_index()

attribute    INDEX attribute_1 attribute_2 attribute_3 attribute_4   timespan           
                                                                          min        max
0          INDEX_1         1.0         3.0         NaN         NaN 2022-01-01 2022-01-31
1          INDEX_1         2.0         3.0         NaN         NaN 2022-02-01 2022-12-31
2          INDEX_2         NaN         NaN         4.0         NaN 2022-01-01 2022-12-31
3          INDEX_3         NaN         NaN         NaN         5.0 2022-01-01 2022-12-31
```

Note that `dropna=False` as groupby option, as in [pandas GroupBy columns with NaN (missing) values](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18429491/12846804), allows NaNs in the grouper, i.e. "NaN ==NaN" being false does not ruin the grouping.

Basically we have your resquested table here. Finally we could discuss bringing the final touch, such as

- flattening the multi-indices,
- or compacting some code lines into one-liners where applicable.

---

**Potential bug?**
Step 3b: I wonder, if an identical combination of attributes were to repeat itself at different time spans, then the min/max approach should fail to reconstitute proper *start_date* and *end_date*. I believe this might be something to take care of.