# Cut date intervals to integrate specific dates

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I have a big dataset with multiple `id` and multiple date intervals.
I am trying to *cut* those intervals to integrate specific dates for each `id`.

Below is a small reproducible example

```py
import pandas as pd

have = {'id': [1,1], 
     'start_date': ['2014-12-01 00:00:00', '2015-03-01 00:00:00'], 
     'end_date': ['2015-02-28 23:59:59', '2015-05-31 23:59:59']}
have = pd.DataFrame(data=have)
have

   id           start_date             end_date
0   1  2014-12-01 00:00:00  2015-02-28 23:59:59
1   1  2015-03-01 00:00:00  2015-05-31 23:59:59
```

```py
# Specific dates to integrate
specific_dt = ['2015-01-01 00:00:00', '2015-03-31 00:00:00']
```

```
want = {'id': [1,1,1,1], 
        'start_date': ['2014-12-01 00:00:00',
                       '2015-01-01 00:00:00',
                       '2015-03-01 00:00:00',
                       '2015-03-31 00:00:00'], 
        'end_date': ['2014-12-31 23:59:59',
                     '2015-02-28 23:59:59',
                     '2015-03-30 23:59:59',
                     '2015-05-31 23:59:59']}
want = pd.DataFrame(data=want)
want

   id           start_date             end_date
0   1  2014-12-01 00:00:00  2014-12-31 23:59:59
1   1  2015-01-01 00:00:00  2015-02-28 23:59:59
2   1  2015-03-01 00:00:00  2015-03-30 23:59:59
3   1  2015-03-31 00:00:00  2015-05-31 23:59:59
```

I was thinking to loop through all `start_date` and `end_date` to check if the any of the specific dates are in between but my dataset is quite big.

Please note that apart from these 3 columns, there are 30+ others columns in the df. I would like to be able to create these intervals in place.

Comment: Can't you sort the start dates and then loop through only once? (I must admit that I don't fully understand what you are going for, though)

Comment: Also, are all the start and end date intervals disjoint?

Comment: legends and @Zorgoth, i opened a chat because I find this question interesting. Input data and instructions are not quite sufficient as of now. Join if interested: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255383/discussion-between-oca-and-zorgoth

Comment: "I am trying to cut those intervals to integrate specific dates for each id." <-- Does this mean you have a different list of "specific dates" for each id? In which case new dates input data should be presented as a dataframe or dictionary of {'id' : specific dates}

Answer (score 1):

Considering edge cases not specified by OP yet possible, that my previous answer doesn't take into account:

- input data didn't come out already sorted by id and date,
- several 'id' might have overlapping time spans,
- each extra date might cut in more than once (up to once per 'id').

Then it's a case of `groupby('id').apply()` that still prevents any `for` loop over the whole dataframe.

---

**Alternative input**

```py
# Alternative input with more than one 'id' and overlapping time intervals
have = pd.DataFrame({'id'        : [1, 1, 2], 
                     'start_date': ['2014-12-01 00:00:00', '2015-03-01 00:00:00', '2015-1-15 00:00:00'], 
                     'end_date'  : ['2015-02-28 23:59:59', '2015-05-31 23:59:59', '2015-03-15 00:00:00']})

have['start_date'] = have['start_date'].apply(pd.to_datetime)
have['end_date'] = have['end_date'].apply(pd.to_datetime)

# add extra column representing "30+ other columns"
have['other'] = ['A', 'B','C']

   id start_date            end_date other
0   1 2014-12-01 2015-02-28 23:59:59     A
1   1 2015-03-01 2015-05-31 23:59:59     B
2   2 2015-01-15 2015-03-15 00:00:00     C
```

---

**Processing**

1. Pre-processing: sorting by date

   ```
   have.sort_values(by=['start_date'], inplace=True)
   ```
2. Define group operation

Now we're about to group by 'id' and apply the following transformation to each group:

```py
def single_id_cut(dfid):
    '''
    For groupby().apply(~),
    Operate date cuts on single 'id' group
    '''
    # Only insert relevant dates (i.e. that are within group time boundaries)
    new_dates = specific_dt[(specific_dt > dfid.start_date.min()) & (specific_dt<dfid.end_date.max())]
    new_start_dates = pd.concat([dfid.start_date, new_dates                           ]).sort_values()
    new_end_dates   = pd.concat([dfid.end_date,   new_dates - pd.tseries.offsets.Day()]).sort_values()
    
    return pd.concat([dfid, pd.DataFrame({'start_date': new_dates})], axis=0 # Add new start dates
            ).sort_values(by='start_date').reset_index(drop=True             # Sort by ascending start dates
            ).assign(end_date = new_end_dates.values                         # Substitute the new end dates
            ).ffill(                                                         # Forward fill gaps in all other columns
            ).astype({'id':'int'})                                           # Ensure 'id' stays as integer after fill
```

3. Apply

```py
have.groupby('id').apply(single_id_cut).reset_index(drop=True)

   id start_date            end_date other
0   1 2014-12-01 2014-12-31 00:00:00     A
1   1 2015-01-01 2015-02-28 23:59:59     A
2   1 2015-03-01 2015-03-30 00:00:00     B
3   1 2015-03-31 2015-05-31 23:59:59     B
4   2 2015-01-15 2015-03-15 00:00:00     C
```

Edge cases accounted for.

Comment: @Zorgoth Please feel free to examine this one. It answers your feedback. I've reused your suggested alternative input data.

Comment: Your code works, but you somehow ended up with an incorrect final dataframe in your written answer; index 4 in the final answer should be split at 2015-03-01, which I did get when I ran your code.

Comment: Posted the correct answer in chat, all that needs to be edited is copy-pasting that in instead of the last dataframe printed in your answer.

Comment: For fun, I compared our two solutions' performance on a df of length 30000. My original answer is very slow, but the updated answer I just put in my edit is very fast, running in under 1.6 seconds vs over 30 seconds for your code. Sometimes for loops are faster!

Comment: I suspect you can optimize your answer by using more in place operations.

Comment: I got it down from 33 seconds to 27 seconds with inplace operations. But I think the overhead of the pandas operations is just too much to get to the level of performance I demonstrated.

Comment: Incidentally there were 20000 ids in the dataframe I used for testing. I suspect your code's performance will improve if applied to a df with fewer ids and more rows per id.

Comment: Oh, I made an error earlier. `specific_dt` has `3-31`, not `3-01` like I was thinking. Your output is correct but doesn't demonstrate the fact that your code handles ids separately. Just change the 03 in end date of the id=2 row to an 04.

Comment: It's the principle of groupby('id') to handle values of 'id' separately. That is not to be demonstrated, unless you're up to open up and debug pandas code.

Comment: I said your code worked correctly.

Comment: All right. That being said, I agree that reducing the number or `concat` may increase performance.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an efficient solution. We convert to datetime objects for easy comparison, ensure that the start dates are sorted, then we iterate through `specific_dt` only once per id, as implemented in the code below.

I have not tested this code in cases where `start_date` or `end_date` is in `specific_dt`; it may need tweaks in such a case.

EDIT: Fixed code to actually change `have` inplace. Note that my iteration method will add the new information into `have` directly. The new `have` will not be in the order of your `want`, but you can easily fix that in place with inplace `DataFrame.sort_values` and `DataFrame.reset_index`.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import datetime


have = {'id': [1, 1],
        'start_date': ['2014-12-01 00:00:00', '2015-03-01 00:00:00'],
        'end_date': ['2015-02-28 23:59:59', '2015-05-31 23:59:59']}
have = pd.DataFrame(data=have)
have['start_date'] = have['start_date'].apply(pd.to_datetime)
have['end_date'] = have['end_date'].apply(pd.to_datetime)

specific_dt = list(map(pd.to_datetime,
                       ['2015-01-01 00:00:00', '2015-03-31 00:00:00']))


have.sort_values(['id', 'start_date'], inplace=True)
last_id = None
newrows = {}


for id_, start_date, end_date in have[['id', 'start_date', 'end_date']].values:
    if id_ != last_id:
        iter_ = iter(specific_dt)
        next_date = True
        newdates = {}
        i = 0
        newdates[i] = []
        if last_id is not None:
            if not newdates[max(newdates)]:
                newdates.pop(max(newdates))
            newrows[id_] = newdates
    last_id = id_
    last_date = start_date
    if next_date is not None:
        if next_date is True:
            try:
                next_date = next(iter_)
            except StopIteration:
                next_date = None
                newdates[i].append([start_date, end_date])
        while next_date is not None and next_date < end_date:
            if start_date < next_date and next_date < end_date:
                newdates[i].append([last_date, next_date - datetime.timedelta(1)])
                last_date = next_date
            try:
                next_date = next(iter_)
            except StopIteration:
                next_date = None
                newdates[i].append([last_date, end_date])
                break
        if next_date is not None:
            newdates[i].append([last_date, end_date])
    else:
        newdates[i].append([start_date, next_date])
    i += 1
    newdates[i] = []
if not newdates[max(newdates)]:
    newdates.pop(max(newdates))
newrows[id_] = newdates

last_id = None
for index, row in have[['id', 'start_date',
                        'end_date']].to_dict('index').items():
    if row['id'] != last_id:
        i = 0
    last_id = row['id']
    for j, newrow in enumerate(newrows[id_][i]):
        if j == 0:
            have.loc[index][['start_date', 'end_date']] = newrow
        else:
            idx = max(have.index) + 1
            have.loc[idx] = have.loc[index]
            have.loc[idx][['start_date', 'end_date']] = newrow
    i += 1
```

EDIT: Adding much more efficient version of code that doesn't work in place, but runs over 20 times faster.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import datetime
import time


have = {'id': sum([[i*2, i*2, i*2+1] for i in range(1, 10001)], []),
        'start_date': ['2014-12-01 00:00:00', '2015-03-01 00:00:00',
                       '2015-1-15 00:00:00']*10000,
        'end_date': ['2015-02-28 23:59:59', '2015-05-31 23:59:59',
                     '2015-03-15 00:00:00']*10000}
have = pd.DataFrame(data=have)
have['start_date'] = have['start_date'].apply(pd.to_datetime)
have['end_date'] = have['end_date'].apply(pd.to_datetime)
have['other'] = ['A', 'B', 'C']*10000

specific_dt = list(map(pd.to_datetime,
                       ['2015-01-01 00:00:00', '2015-03-01 00:00:00']))
start_time = time.time()
iter_ = iter(specific_dt)

have.sort_values(['id', 'start_date'], inplace=True)
last_id = None
newrows = {}
newdates = None


for index, row in have[['id', 'start_date', 'end_date']].to_dict('index').items():
    id_ = row['id']
    start_date = row['start_date']
    end_date = row['end_date']
    if id_ != last_id:
        if last_id is not None:
            if not newdates[max(newdates)]:
                newdates.pop(max(newdates))
            newrows[last_id] = newdates
        iter_ = iter(specific_dt)
        next_date = True
        newdates = {}
        i = 0
        newdates[i] = []
    last_id = id_
    last_date = start_date
    if next_date is not None:
        if next_date is True:
            try:
                next_date = next(iter_)
            except StopIteration:
                next_date = None
                newdates[i].append([start_date, end_date, index])
        while next_date is not None and next_date < end_date:
            if start_date < next_date and next_date < end_date:
                newdates[i].append([last_date,
                                    next_date - datetime.timedelta(1),
                                    index])
                last_date = next_date
            try:
                next_date = next(iter_)
            except StopIteration:
                next_date = None
                newdates[i].append([last_date, end_date, index])
                break
        if next_date is not None:
            newdates[i].append([last_date, end_date, index])
    else:
        newdates[i].append([start_date, next_date, index])
    i += 1
    newdates[i] = []
if not newdates[max(newdates)]:
    newdates.pop(max(newdates))
newrows[id_] = newdates
row_dict_list = []
for id_ in newrows:
    for i in newrows[id_]:
        for start_date, end_date, index in newrows[id_][i]:
            dict_ = have.loc[index].to_dict()
            dict_.update({'id': id_,
                          'start_date': start_date,
                          'end_date': end_date})
            row_dict_list.append(dict_)
final = pd.DataFrame(row_dict_list)
print(time.time() - start_time)
print(final)
```

Comment: I just realized this is only a partial solution as I didn't convert back to a dataframe. I will fix this soon.

Comment: also if i get it right, OP has already considered looping through dates and is looking for something more vectorized, because of actual df size

Comment: I'll not be so bold as to say there is no solution more efficient than mine, but I think that it is impossible to avoid looping through some columns of the dataframe.

Comment: just did ;) Seriously, I had forgotten about this question, so thank you for reminding me of it. Your opinion on my answer would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You emphasize that there are many more columns but don't specify what is supposed to happen to them. Here I assume that, when splitting time intervals, children intervals inherit their parents values.

To illustrate this, I have added one 'other' column with a different value in each row.

---

**Modifications to OP's input data**

*have*

```py
# Format dates as datetime
have[['start_date', 'end_date']] = have[['start_date', 'end_date']].apply(pd.to_datetime)

# add extra column representing "30+ other columns"
have['other'] = ['A', 'B']

   id start_date            end_date other
0   1 2014-12-01 2015-02-28 23:59:59     A
1   1 2015-03-01 2015-05-31 23:59:59     B
```

*specific dates*

```py
# Convert list into a pd.Series with datetime format
specific_dt = pd.Series(specific_dt).astype('datetime64[ns]')

0   2015-01-01
1   2015-03-31
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Now sorting by time will go smoothly.

---

**Processing**

Step 1. Calculate the new dates vectors

Both updated dates vectors can be known straight up:

```py
new_start_dates = pd.concat([have.start_date, specific_dt                           ]).sort_values() # unused
new_end_dates   = pd.concat([have.end_date,   specific_dt - pd.tseries.offsets.Day()]).sort_values() # used next

new_start_dates 

0   2014-12-01
0   2015-01-01
1   2015-03-01
1   2015-03-31
dtype: datetime64[ns]

new_end_dates   

0   2014-12-31 00:00:00
0   2015-02-28 23:59:59
1   2015-03-30 00:00:00
1   2015-05-31 23:59:59
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Notes on this:

- The added end dates are *specific_dt* **minus one day**. For substracting a datetime period from a Series, see [subtract one day from a pandas dataframe date column](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63855270/12846804).
- These new start dates are not going to be used. That is because entering them by concatenation in step 2 makes propagation of "extra columns" quite straightforward.

Step 2. Add the new dates to inital table

This is your *want*:

```py
final = pd.concat([have, pd.DataFrame({'start_date': specific_dt})], axis=0 # Add new start dates
         ).sort_values(by='start_date').reset_index(drop=True               # Sort by ascending start dates
         ).assign(end_date = new_end_dates.values                           # Substitute the new end dates
         ).ffill(                                                           # Forward fill the other columns
         ).astype({'id':'int'})                                             # Restore 'id' integer type (was lot by concat with NaN)

  id start_date            end_date other
0  1 2014-12-01 2014-12-31 00:00:00     A
1  1 2015-01-01 2015-02-28 23:59:59     A
2  1 2015-03-01 2015-03-30 00:00:00     B
3  1 2015-03-31 2015-05-31 23:59:59     B
```

Comment: How does this answer handle the case where there are multiple ids? I think it can be modified, but I don't think it quite works yet.

Comment: @Zorgoth id gets inherited from parent id, just like 'other'. In truth OP's minimal input is insufficient to cover cases we think of. Shall we agree on an alternative input? Thanks for feedback btw

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the dates are supposed to be handled independently for each id.

Comment: When a row gets split by an added date, both children rows inherit its id. There's no issue with id here.

Comment: Consider have = {'id': [1, 1, 2],
        'start_date': ['2014-12-01 00:00:00', '2015-03-01 00:00:00',
                       '2015-1-15 00:00:00'],
        'end_date': ['2015-02-28 23:59:59', '2015-05-31 23:59:59',
                     '2015-03-15 00:00:00']}
have = pd.DataFrame(data=have)
have['start_date'] = have['start_date'].apply(pd.to_datetime)
have['end_date'] = have['end_date'].apply(pd.to_datetime)

When you apply your code, the interval for id 2 will, incorrectly, be 2015-01-15-2015-03-15, when it should be split.

Comment: This is because you are mashing together all the start and end dates for different ids. You really do need to consider them separately.

Comment: Run the code. You will see the result.

Comment: id start_date            end_date
0   1 2014-12-01 2014-12-31 00:00:00
1   1 2015-01-01 2015-02-28 23:59:59
2   2 2015-01-15 2015-03-15 00:00:00
3   1 2015-03-01 2015-03-30 00:00:00
4   1 2015-03-31 2015-05-31 23:59:59

Comment: In my code you will note that I sort by id and then by date. The fact that you are not sorting by id is what I mean when I say you are mashing the dates together.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255383/discussion-between-oca-and-zorgoth).